# understanding iris data and rpart application in it

Tags: r

Hi I am working with the iris data and have been able to compile to following code (I say compile because I have written the simple ones and got the rest over R blogs and help sites but I am having difficulty interpreting them. My goal is basically to understand rpart and its utility:

```
iris=read.csv("iris.csv")
kmeans.result <- kmeans(iris, 3)
#I received this warning message after the above command and could not understand why: 
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In kmeans(iris, 3) : NAs introduced by coercion

table(iris$Species, kmeans.result$cluster)
plot(iris[c("Sepal.length", "Sepal.width")], col = kmeans.result$cluster)
points(kmeans.result$centers[,c("Sepal.length", "Sepal.width")], col = 1:3,
pch=8, cex=2)

#I installed rpart and got the second command from a blog (did not write that myself) that I just modified for the data name and got a plot with out labels:
library(rpart)

iris.rp <-rpart(Species ~ . ,                         
                data = iris,                                            
                method = "class",                     
                parms = list(split = "information"), 
                maxsurrogate = 0,                     
                cp = 0,                              
                minsplit = 5,                                                         
                minbucket = 2,                        
                         )


plot(iris.rp)
```

any help to just understand/improve the same would be very helpful!

Comment: I don't know where "iris.csv" comes from, but if you are using the built-in iris dataset, the error is because `kmeans(...)` requires a numeric matrix or data frame. The last column of iris is char, which is coerced to NA. Try `kmeans(iris[,1:4],3)`

Comment: @jlhoward yes. that's the iris data set. thanks.it solved the error issue. can you help interpreting the rpart section if possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic errors and then a request for a statistical tutoring session. No coding content.